# tkinter questionnaire has warnings

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-menu

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Button
LARGE_FONT= ("Venom Rockets", 12)

def confirm():
    confirm = "Confirmed" + str(var.get())
    label.config(text = selection)

class config_panel(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = ()

        for F in (MenuPage, Page1, Page2):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.show_frame(MenuPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class MenuPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Configuration Menu", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Abort", fg="red", command=quit)
        button.pack()
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Start Configuration",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2))

class Page1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Configuration Page 1", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        labl1 = tk.Label(self, text="Please confirm launch location", front=LARGE_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="LC39A.",
                         command=sel)
        R1.pack(anchor=W)
        R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="LC39B.",
                         command=sel)
        R2.pack(anchor=W)
        R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="LC49.",
                         command=sel)
        R3.pack(anchor=W)
        R4 = Radiobutton(root, text="LC13.",
                         command=sel)
        R4.pack(anchor=W)
        R5 = Radiobutton(root, text="LC37B.",
                         command=sel)
        R5.pack(anchor=W)
        R6 = Radiobutton(root, text="LC40.",
                         command=sel)
        R6.pack(anchor=W)
        R7 = Radiobutton(root, text="LC41.",
                         command=sel)
        R7.pack(anchor=W)
        R8 = Radiobutton(root, text="LC47.",
                         command=sel)
        R8.pack(anchor=W)
        Nextbtn = tk.Button(self, text="Confirm, Next.",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2))
        Nextbtn.pack()

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Configuration Page 2", front=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Please confirm rocket direction", front=LARGE_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        R1 = Raidobutton(root, text="North.",
                         command=sel)
        R1.pack(anchor=W)
        R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="East.",
                         command=sel)
        R2.pack(anchor=W)
        R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="South.",
                         command=sel)
        R3.pack(anchor=W)
        R4 = Radiobutton(root, text="West.",
                         command=sel)
        R4.pack(anchor=W)
        Nextbtn = tk.Button(self, text="Confirm, Next.",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MenuPage))
        Nextbtn.pack()

app = config_panel()
app.mainloop()
```

that is currently all my code, but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Samuel Berlet/Desktop/rfnirfi.py", line 105, in <module>
    app = config_panel()
  File "C:/Users/Samuel Berlet/Desktop/rfnirfi.py", line 24, in __init__
    frame = F(container, self)
  File "C:/Users/Samuel Berlet/Desktop/rfnirfi.py", line 37, in __init__
    tk.Frame.__init(self, parent)
AttributeError: type object 'Frame' has no attribute '_MenuPage__init'
```

When I try to run it. I want to make a kind of questionnaire. Like there will be a menu page with Configure or Abort Abort will shut the whole Thing down Configure will open Another window that will have set1 of the questions (launch location), then after that set 2 etc. How Do I make this please can someone Help Me With the Code.

Comment: I deleted my answer because there's too much wrong with this code to fix it entirely. In the future, please accept answers when they answer your original question, and ask any new questions as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In the final line in the traceback, put a double underscore (`__`) after, as well as before `__init__`. There are other problems in your code.